# How do I retrieve streaming results using Grpc in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, grpc, grpc-dotnet

I am building a .NetCore application using gRPC.

I'm having issues constructing code to handle streaming results.

**Consider the following protobuf definition:**

```
service SampleService
{
    rpc RegisterClient(G_ClientRequest) returns (stream G_ClientResponse) { }
}
```

**Here is a code snippet to read results from the stream:**

```
public ConnectToClient()
{
    var results = Client.RegisterClient(new G_ClientRequest() 
    { 
        ClientName = "Foo",
        DateTimeStamp = new Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Timestamp()
    });
    
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    foreach (var result in results.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync(cancellationToken: cts.Token))
    {

    }   
}
```

I've been googling around and found something similar to my above code for handling streaming results. However the code does not compile.
**ReadAllAsync()** is not available in the interface definition for **IAsyncStreamReader**.

Is this functionality not available/supported in .Net Core? I'm using the latest stable version of Grpc (2.38).

If this is not available to me, how do I retrieve results from the **ResponseStream** in .Net Core?

Thx, JohnB

Comment: Third-party, but protobuf-net.Grpc exposes the regular gRPC APIs using IAsyncEnumerable-T instead, so: `await foreach` and you're done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReadAllAsync is an extension included in Grpc.Core, if you have installed the Nuget package Grpc.Net.Client just add:

```
using Grpc.Core;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the gRPC docs, interface IAsyncStreamReader does not have a ReadAllAsync() method.

https://grpc.github.io/grpc/csharp/api/Grpc.Core.IAsyncStreamReader-1.html

Comment: Yes I saw that. Then I also saw some feature requests that were asking for it in addition to some samples that appeared to be using it..., thus the confusion.